# double to int (or long, long long) conversion sometimes is not good

Tags: objective-c, ios, int, double

I am trying to convert quite big double number to int (or long or long long), but have some difficulties. Almost always it converts good, but not sometimes:

My code:

```
double price = 12345678.900000;
double hundredNumber = price * 100;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:hundredNumber];
int tempNumber = [number intValue];
```

All goes good, until tempNumber. it logs out 1234567889, but it should be 1234567890 (...**89** - ...**90**)
Does anyone know why it could happen and how to convert correctly?

P. S. I am trying to implement backspace to value (e.x. 123.45, after that it should be 12.34). Maybe anyone had implemented something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You're always going to get the risk of rounding errors if you're using floating point numbers.

Why not always store prices as a `long long`?

i.e. instead of £5.50, store 550p. That way you will never have any rounding issues at all.

Comment: This is the only correct answer here so far. Floating point numbers are not exact. If you're dealing with something you know the needed precision for (like currency), store that as integers.

Comment: but this rounding is not faire, i know what rounding is, but why 90 becomes 89? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: That tells me you haven't had much experience of floating point numbers :) You say `price = 12345678.900000` but it might be stored as `12345678.90000000001` because of rounding errors in the floating point storage. Usually these errors are very small but sometimes they can build up and cause errors like the one you are seeing now. If you want absolute precision, use integers. Also, this site is interesting : http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

As commented, I would be careful with the roundings, because of the possible errors.

One possible solution is to work with doubles like Google does with coordinates in Android: multiplying them by 1E6. If you operate with integers then you'll safe much more CPU cycle than operating with doubles. Try this out:

```
double priceDouble = 33.f / 34.f;
NSLog(@"double: %f", priceDouble);

NSInteger priceInteger = (NSInteger)(priceDouble * 1E6);
NSLog(@"int: %d", priceInteger);

NSNumber * priceNumberWithDouble = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:priceInteger];
priceDouble = [priceNumberWithDouble doubleValue];
NSLog(@"double: %f", priceDouble);

NSNumber * priceNumberWithInteger = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:priceInteger];
priceInteger = [priceNumberWithInteger integerValue];
NSLog(@"int: %d", priceInteger);

double test = ((double)priceInteger)/1E6;
NSLog(@"Test: %f",test);
```

My output is the following:

```
double: 0.970588
int: 970588
double: 970588.000000
int: 970588
Test: 0.970588
```